# How can I disguise my own name (for my screen) in chat on a recording?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I'm starting a channel for gaming, and I like my current Minecraft username, however if I change it to match my new one bad things will occur (and I don't want to buy a new username because then I have no stats).

Is there either:

- A setting I can change that will modify how I see my own name in chat; like /nick from Hypixel but without /nick?
- A text replacement mod that changes my name - wherever it is in chat - to a different name? (e.g. Someone says "Hi JB" it's changed to "Hi mr_big" on my screen?)

Kinda not sure if this is on-topic for here, but I'd love to know any ways to do this.

Comment: Why would something bad happen if you changed it?

Comment: Also, what version are you playing on? I know of a mod that may work with some configuration but it only supports 1.8.9 and 1.12.2. Most of the PVP/Hypixel community plays on 1.8.9 so it’s still being updated.

Comment: Just because people might not know it was me @SamHill. Also I'm on 1.8.9 - can you send me the link to that mod?

Comment: How bad would it be if your current username were to end up in the recording? There'd always be a risk of that from an imperfect replacement, a bug or something you would've needed to do that you forget at some point (like after reinstalling or updating it or something). Trying to remove every instance of what you don't want people to see is a much safer option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out [Chat Triggers.](https://www.chattriggers.com/) It’s not really a mod so much as a framework used for making mods. Basically the Roblox or Dreams of mods, if that makes sense.

There is a text filter and replacement module that should pull off what you’re trying to accomplish, or if you have knowledge of JavaScript you could make your own.

Comment: Do you mean JavaScript, or Java? They're two different programming languages. Minecraft is written in Java.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 It’s JavaScript. Minecraft is Java but ChatTriggers uses JavaScript for their modules. More information can be found on their website.

Comment: "A framework for Minecraft Forge that allows for client modifications to be scripted in JavaScript"

Comment: Note that this mod's only compatible with Forge, which is quite a heavy mod loader. It might not be for everyone. I'd advise also installing OptiFine if you want to install Forge just to run this.

Comment: If you want to hide your name perfectly you will have a lot of trouble, even with mods (e.g. what if they say "hi J B" or "hi JackB" or someone looks up the other users?).  You probably need to choose between blurring out all PII entirely or accepting the fact that online entities are public, especially if you plan to stream.